# caching authorized content in microsoft CDN

Tags: cache-control, azure-cdn, microsoft-cdn

I have a web service and microsoft CDN on top of it. I am using bearer token to gain access to the service.
When I call service directly I get a header back:

`Cache-Control: public,max-age=6000`

but when I call it via CDN I get:

`X-Cache: CONFIG_NOCACHE`

I suspect it is because authorized content is not being cached by default and I am wondering if I can setup some rules to bypass it and make it cache no matter if I pass Authorization header or not.

Comment: The X-Cache header with the value of CONFIG_NOCACHE indicates that the requested content was ineligible for caching. This status may be due to a customer-specific configuration or cache response headers. Check below Docs if it helps [Manage expiration of web content in Azure CDN | Microsoft Docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-cloud-service-content.md)

Comment: hey Naveen, so far I have concluded that I need to use rules engine to setup the rules to make it work, but I haven't found a solution yet to how exactly to set it up.
This issue seems to happen on microsoft CDN but not, e.g. Verizon so if I just switch to using Verizon it is working without any problems even if I pass Authorization header